# json from Android to php input

Tags: java, php, android, post

I am trying to post data as json from Android to a PHP script, however it just doesn't seem to  read the data I am sending.

PHP

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($json);
```

Data

```
{"Date":"2012-05-31","Device_ID":"soaptester","Time":"15:22:59","Longitude":0.33,"Latitude":51.01}
```

Java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sp = getSharedPreferences("SoapTester", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String address = sp.getString("address", null);
    if (address == null) {
        sp.edit().putString("address", "http://192.168.0.8/lt_data/test.php").commit();
    }

    addressTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    addressTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            sp.edit().putString("address", String.valueOf(v.getText())).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });

    track = new LocationTrack();
    track.setDate("2012-05-31");
    track.setTime("15:22:59");
    track.setLatitude(51.01);
    track.setLongitude(0.33);
    track.setDevice_ID("soaptester");

    output = new Gson().toJson(track);

    outputTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    outputTextView.setText(output);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    addressTextView.setText(sp.getString("address", ""));
}

public void sendPost(View view) {

    ServiceResponse r = Resting.post(sp.getString("address", ""), 80, output, EncodingTypes.UTF8);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.response)).setText(String.valueOf(r));

}
```

After loads of testing i just can't seem to find out why it is not receiving the data from the android application.

Comment: Did you miss `$json = json_decode($json);` before accessing it in the code? And what is an output for `print_r($json);`

Comment: @Alexander I actually have more code below that posts the data to a .txt file for storage purposes (temp).

Comment: Do you have anything from `file_get_contents('php://input')`? If you have a correct string here, then problem is in your PHP code, if not then problem is in the Android part of app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use some tools like netcat to see if you sending your json message correctly or not. Or try to use some tools for network traffic (wireshark, tcpdump).